# Update for update?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way of doing a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` but with a nested update returning rather than a select? The scenario I'm thinking of looks a bit like:

```
UPDATE cars
SET model='myModel', ownerID=(
  UPDATE owners
  SET cars_owned = cars_owned + 1
  WHERE name = 'fred'
  RETURNING id
)
WHERE id = 'abc123';
```

Is there any way to do this atomically without a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.  You can use a CTE:

```
WITH o as (
      UPDATE owners
          SET cars_owned = cars_owned + 1
      WHERE name = 'fred'
      RETURNING id
     )
UPDATE cars
    SET model = 'myModel',
        ownerID = (SELECT id FROM o);
WHERE id = 'abc123';
```

Comment: Interesting! Is this assured to be atomic?

Comment: @tengbretson: yes. A single statement is always atomic